# 500 error on checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, sagepay

Bit of an odd issue on one of my client sites, they are using SagePay which is upgraded to the latest version. However after you finish going through the checkout before the confirmation page there is a 500 error. But when you refresh the browser the confirmation appears.

Any ideas on why its causing it. The url is https://www.bathroomluxuries.co.uk/

exception log:

```
2016-06-22T12:46:33+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Unable to find the transaction for the &lt;t3mtxid&gt; supplied.' in /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/Mage.php:563
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePayReporting/Model/Sagepayreporting.php(162): Mage::throwException('Unable to find ...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePayReporting/Model/Sagepayreporting.php(226): Ebizmarts_SagePayReporting_Model_SagePayReporting->basicOperation('getT3MDetail', '<t3mtxid>466955...')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Block/Info/Suite.php(215): Ebizmarts_SagePayReporting_Model_SagePayReporting->getT3MDetail('4669555631')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sagepaysuite/payment/info/base.phtml(143): Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Block_Info_Suite->getThirdmanBreakdown('4669555631')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#5 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('info', true)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Payment.php(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('info')
#11 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Payment->_toHtml()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('order_payment', true)
#14 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/Info.php(112): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('order_payment')
#15 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml(45): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info->getPaymentHtml()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#17 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#18 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#19 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#20 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(303): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml(38): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info))
#23 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#24 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#25 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#26 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#27 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#30 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#31 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#32 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#33 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#34 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#35 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#36 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#37 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#38 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#39 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#40 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(119): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#41 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->viewAction()
#42 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#43 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#44 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#45 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#46 /var/www/vhosts/bathroom-luxuries/htdocs/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#47 {main}
```

Comment: can you check log files inside var folder

Comment: can you go to index.php file present in root and uncomment this line `#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);`  and check the checkout page

Comment: That exception output appears not entirely related as it's trigger by the view order page in the admin panel.

Comment: Are you saying that it could be down to to a trigger in the order page Peter, how would I check this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error with `&lt;t3mtxid&gt;` which actually is

```
<t3mtxid>
```

If you do a Google search it shows up to be a problem with SagePay. It is listed in their [documentation](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/6946/download-document/Reporting_and_Admin_API_Integration_Guideline_31012014.pdf?token=43adwgSX3nFXe7bBrOx-NX9U0HglniU5eNg4CArSup0) (pdf document) with an error code:

```
2242    Unable to find the transaction for the <t3mtxid> supplied.
```

What you could do:

1. Try to disable the SagePay extension, and check if that was the problem
2. If it was the problem ask support from the developers or first try to update it to the newest version of their extension

Comment: I have updated to the newest version, and I have tested this on the development site, we are still getting the same error, with the latest update.

Comment: Your best chance is just to ask support from SagePay themselves. Since the error is documented it is a knows problem. So they will also have a solution. Did you try that allready?